# Get indices of multidimensional numpy array of arbitrary shape and use it on another array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have two multidimensional arrays `a` and `b` of same shape:

```
print(a.shape) -> (100, 20, 3, 3)
print(b.shape) -> (100, 20, 3, 3)
```

Now I only want to get values out of `a` that match a certain condition, for example:

```
wanted_value = 5
result_a = a[a[:, :, :, 0] == wanted_value]
```

That works well, however, now suppose I would like to get data out of another array `b` of indices that correspond to the indices of found elements in array `a`. Is it possible to somehow use the indices I can get from searching array `a` for a certain condition on array `b` to get data out of array `b` corresponding to the same indices of the same shape that array `a` has? I need this because I can not search array `b` for the condition I need but the data/elements of array `b` correspond to array `a` respectively.

Is this possible?
I tried something like this:

```
indices = np.where(a[a[:, :, :, 0] == wanted_value])
results_b = b[indices]
```

Comment: Hint: try checking what `a[:, :, :, 0] == wanted_value` gives you by itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It is even simpler than you expect:

```
b[a[:, :, :, 0] == wanted_value]
```

The way it works is that `a[:, :, :, 0] == wanted_value` by itself *creates a Numpy array* with `dtype=bool`, referred to in the documentation as a *mask*. You can apply it to any array of the same shape.

Comment: so convenient and easy, you gotta love numpy, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Numpy supports boolean indexing i.e when you index a numpy array with a Boolean array all the values with truthvalue of `True` will be  returned. This advanced indexing occurs when obj is an array object of Boolean type. The comparison operators return boolean objects and so these can be used to index.

```
a = np.random.randint(0, 500, (100,20,3,3))
b = np.copy(a)
assert np.array_equal(a[a[:,:,:,0] == 1], b[a[:,:,:,0] == 1])
```

Check official docs from [here](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing).